# Creating Chart using DataVisualization.Charting in .NET 4.0

Tags: wpf, charts, data-visualization

I'm attempting to user System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting to create a line chart.  I've been using the System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit for a while now but would like to get rid of all of my .Net 3.5 references.  I cannot find any sources for examples of charts using DataVisualization.Charting

Using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit...

```
<DVC:Chart Name="mcChart" Width="Auto" Height="225" Padding="0" Margin="0,-5,0,0" >
                                <DVC:Chart.Series>
                                    <DVC:LineSeries x:Name="lsActual" Title=" Expenditures" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Amt}" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource redLineDataPoint}" />
                                    <DVC:LineSeries x:Name="lsBudget" Title=" Budget" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Amt}" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource blueLineDataPoint}"/>
                                    <DVC:LineSeries x:Name="lsProjection" Title=" Projection" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Amt}" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource greenLineDataPoint}" />
                                </DVC:Chart.Series>
                            </DVC:Chart>
```

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting...

?

References

```
    xmlns:wfi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
xmlns:CHR="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

Comment: Is charting built into WPF .NET 4.0 or do you have to use the Toolkit?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use the toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new (FW4.0) charting controls, but they are WindowsForms controls, which means you have to use the [`<WindowsFormsHost>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) container:

1. Add a reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration`
2. Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`
3. Add the following namespace:

   ```
   xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
   ```

Also, there are [some things you have to keep in mind with hybrid applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970911(v=VS.100).aspx).

Besides the above, I think the WindowsForms version of the charting controls is a bit better designed. I'm going to give them a try in a WPF application.

More help:

- [Using Chart Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970911(v=VS.100).aspx)
- [Chart Controls - Helpful Links](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5608a146-872a-4d53-9b2b-bc3c4d0c2f42/chart-controls-helpful-links?forum=MSWinWebChart)
- [Chart Controls for .NET Framework Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=MSWinWebChart)
- [Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET Framework Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11001) (not sure if it's the right version)
- [Another possibly useful post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series)

Download the "Samples Environment"! It has a truckload of examples and guides. I've only had two problems with it: running the executable directly and problems when the path had a `#` in it.